# breezejs v1.3.6 breaks my application

Tags: javascript, breeze

I've updated my client library and server web api dll to latest version.

Now whenever I do an expand on a query, I get that kind of error:

```
unable to locate property: Mandate on type: MandateHistory:#Dom.DirectDebit
```

with the query being :

```
  var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("MandatesHistory")
        .where("Mandate.Id", "==", mandatId).expand("Mandate"); 

    return manager.executeQuery(query.using(service));
```

If I downgrade to 1.3.3 (the client library only), everything works fine.

I would have like to try 1.3.4 or 1.3.5 but I can't find them on the website....

What has changed between 1.3.3 and 1.3.6 that could break my application ?

**EDIT**

**THIS IS THE CODE CAUSING ISSUES :**

In 1.3.6, in the function parseCsdNavProperty, the following code was added:

```
 var constraint = association.referentialConstraint;
    if (!constraint) {
        // TODO: Revisit this later - right now we just ignore many-many and assocs with missing constraints.
        return;
        // Think about adding this back later.
        //if (association.end[0].multiplicity == "*" && association.end[1].multiplicity == "*") {
        //    // many to many relation
        //    ???
        //} else {
        //    throw new Error("Foreign Key Associations must be turned on for this model");
        //}
    }
```

Basically, for the navigation property MandateHistory.Mandate, there is no contraint found, so the code just return. This is the cause of my issue.

In version 1.3.3, there was no check on constraint because first there was the following check which returns false in my case (isScalar is false):

```
 if (toEnd && isScalar) {
        var constraint = association.referentialConstraint;
        if (constraint) {
            var principal = constraint.principal;
            var dependent = constraint.dependent;
            var propRefs;
            if (csdlProperty.fromRole === principal.role) {
                propRefs = toArray(principal.propertyRef);
            } else {
                propRefs = toArray(dependent.propertyRef);
            }
            // will be used later by np._update
            fkNamesOnServer = propRefs.map(__pluck("name"));
        }
    }
```

Can the breeze team look into this ?

**SOLUTION**

Following Jay's suggestion, the .net model had to be changed in order to explicitly set the foreign key association between MandateHistory and Mandate:

```
 public class MandateHistory
 {
    [ForeignKey("Mandate")]
    public int Mandate_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Mandate Mandate { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: I think I have sewn this before recently where you are trying to query on a property before breeze has loaded any relevant entities to see its properties.  To confirm this can you run a query on a mandate and then try your query?  I know it doesn't really help your situation but should make finding the issue easier

Comment: I've investigated further. Breeze raises an exception when searching for the properties Mandate in proto.validate. The Mandate property is not found in the array of properties of MandateHistory. Now the mistery is why this property does not exist on MandateHistory when I use 1.3.6 but it does exist when I use 1.3.3 ????

Comment: by the way, when this query executes, the Mandate metadata is very well known by breeze because in order to view MandatesHistory, I must open a Mandate first.

Comment: I've found out the difference between the two versions. See my EDIT.

Comment: Ok cool, probably need to wait until Jay can come around and give you the expert advice at this point.  If I get a free minute I will try to dig further.

Comment: I've nailed it down to the cause of the issue, see my update. Hopefully someone from breeze team will find the answer.... That bit of code seems ackward anyway (lots of comments with question marks and TODOs :)  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are missing referential constraints in your model. i.e. the Entity Framework thinks that you are not exposing foreign keys. See [Foreign keys in the Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx).

Breeze requires the foreign keys in order to perform it's automatic object linking logic.

This is also described here: [Breeze navigation properties](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the actual .net model (I'm mostly working on the client-side) but I'll check that tomorrow. On the other hand, why would it work with 1.3.3 ? Did you ignore these referential constraints altogether in versions prior to 1.3.6 ?

Comment: In some circumstances, yes, and there were bugs as a result.

Comment: using version 1.3.3, the Mandate property on my MandateHistory Entity is filled with the correct Mandate. So it seems that EF knows about navigation properties otherwise how would it assign the correct Mandate when I do the Expand ? But again I'll need to check the server code tomorrow.

Comment: ok, you were right. With version 1.3.6 of breeze, I had to explicitely set the foreign key in the MandateHistory server-class . See edit