# breezejs: inlineCount is no longer part of the response

Tags: javascript, breeze

I've upgraded the server webapi breeze dll from version 1.2.8 to 1.2.9, and similarly to my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658128/breezejs-v1-3-6-breaks-my-application), I've got a regression bug.

The following ODATA call is successful and returns the data + inlineCount:

```
http://mydomain/api/mandates/Mandates?$orderby=PolicyNumber%20desc&$top=10&$inlinecount=allpages
```

[image]

However, the following ODATA call does not return inlineCount (note that the only difference is the orderby criteria on a complex object):

```
 http://mydomain/api/mandates/Mandates?$orderby=AccountOwner%2FTiersId%20desc&$top=10&$inlinecount=allpages
```

[image]

Can someone look into that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is a bug and it will be fixed in the next release, out later this week or early next week.  The fix has already been made to the version of Breeze on GitHub. (This is what we will be releasing after additional testing and some more small changes).  Thanks for finding it.

Comment: Jay, I'm still having this issue with 1.3.6 In the end, it does not seem to be related to the navigation property issue I've solved in the other thread. Here I just can't sort on a complex object type (AccountOwner.TiersId with AccountOwner being a complex type on the Mandate object). The inlineCount is not returned in this case. Any idea what's going on ?

Comment: ah cool, I'm glad you solved it ! Next time can you just add a new answer instead of editing your previous answer, because otherwise SO does not inform me that you've replied :p And I was stressed out by this bug :)

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Next time - new answer :)

Comment: @JayTraband which files would I need off github to get this to work? Or do you know when it will be released on nuget? Thanks! Breeze rocks :)

Comment: Should be available now on the Breeze website v 1.4.0